# Accessing/assigning global variable inside of key press event function

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas, global-variables

I am attempting to use a key press event function to scroll through plots of data I have generated. The code should do a simple check to see if the current position is a valid index and then update the value of curr_pos upon a given key stroke.

```
     def test_key():
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

        curr_pos=0
        dt = 1
        numtimes = 5

        def key_event(e):
            global curr_pos

            if curr_pos - dt <= 0:
                if e.key == "right":
                    curr_pos = curr_pos + dt
                else:
                    return
            elif curr_pos + dt >= numtimes:
                if e.key == "left":
                    curr_pos = curr_pos - dt
                else:
                    return
            else:
                if e.key == "right":
                    curr_pos = curr_pos + dt
                elif e.key == "left":
                    curr_pos = curr_pos - dt
                else: 
                    return
                ax.cla()
                ax.plot([1,1,1], [1,1,1])
                ax.title('time index: '+str(curr_pos))
                fig.canvas.draw()
        fig = plt.figure()
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', key_event)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot([1,1,1], [1,1,1])
        plt.show()
```

The code is simplified quite a bit, obviously im not trying to plot a bunch of ones here. I read the data from a file and didn't want to have to deal with that while uploading this question. Anyways, curr_pos will eventually be used to choose the index of the data that will be plotted. This should recreate the error I am having though which is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ckswee/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 216, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ckswee/Documents/strahl/test_key.py", line 18, in key_event
    if curr_pos - dt <= 0:
NameError: name 'curr_pos' is not defined
```

Do I have to define my variable curr_pos in a different way to be able to access it like this?

Comment: `ax.set_title` instead of `ax.title`. And of course the variable must be global in every function it's used in.

Comment: Imports should go at the top of the file. Why are you defining a function inside another one?

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at my answer? I can give more explanation if it is still unclear

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have given `curr_pos` is being defined as a local variable in the scope of `test_key()`, **not** the global scope. Consider the following simple example:

```py
def a():
    i = 0
    def b():
        print(i)
    b()

a()
```

Which will work without error because `print(i)` is referencing the variable `i` which was declared in the scope of `a()`. Now if we do

```py
def a():
    i = 0
    def b():
        global i
        print(i)
    b()

a()
```

`print(i)` is now looking for an `i` which was declared at the global scope, and finding none it throws an error. The correct declaration would be

```py
def a():
    global i
    i = 0
    def b():
        global i
        print(i)
    b()

a()
```

Or

```py
I = 0
def a():
    def b():
        global i
        print(i)
    b()

a()
```

Either of which will work correctly